# How to hear sound from mpmovieplayer at a specific time using UISlider?

Tags: ios7, ios6

I'm working on an iOS movie editor project. For this editor, i use MPMoviePlayer to show the video file selected by the user.
I use custom controls, and I have a UISlider that enables the user to move the player's currentTime position. When the user touches the slider, movie is paused and its currentTime changes along with the UISlider's value.
Everything works perfectly, but now i need to let the user hear the sound at this currentTime position.
For those who know iMovie, when you move your mouse over a movie event, you see the image and hear the sound at this position, and that's what i'd like in my editor.
I've tried to call player's play method with à NSTimer to stop after 0.2 seconds, but the result is kind of messy.
Has anyone already achieved to do something like this ?
Thanks !
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Seeking takes time; that's why you've ended up using a timer. The real problem here is that MPMoviePlayerController, while convenient because it gives you controls, is a blunt instrument; it's just a massive simplified convenience built on top of AVFoundation. But you don't need the built-in controls, so I would suggest throwing away your entire implementation and getting down to the real stuff, using AVFoundation instead (AVPlayer etc). Now you have a coherent way to seek and get a notification when the seek has completed (`seekToTime:completionHandler:`), so you'll be able to start playing as soon as possible. Plus, AVFoundation is the level where you'll be doing all your "editing" anyway.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer. I'm going to give it a try. If i understand well, things should happen like this : slider's UIControlEventValueChanged calls player's seekToTime:completionHandler and then, when completionHandler completes the AVPlayer's play method can be called. I hope this approach will be much faster than the actual.